# Why don't I see a button for "improve" on tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, editing, review-tools

When reviewing edits there is text inviting to improve the edit:

> Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users. (less)
>
> Approve edits you know are correct
> Reject those you know are wrong
> Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

but I see buttons only for approve, reject, and skip. How to improve the edit?

In case it makes a difference: I am using Firefox 16.0.2 (Mozilla Firefox Ubuntu canonical - 1.0)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It might help. :)

Comment: I don't know how to make a screenshot. But it wouldn't show anything else than I mentioned.

Comment: Well it would have been useful in case you hadn't noticed something, that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking at an edit suggested to a *tag wiki*.

While you have [the ability to *vote to approve*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) these edits, you haven't yet earned [the right to edit them *directly*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) - so the "improve" button is unavailable.

[dmckee, as a moderator](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/on-reviewing-edits/2752#2752), has all the rights and so sees the "improve" button regardless of his reputation.

(and yes, just removing/disabling the button is a bit weird, but the alternative would allow you to create a sort of chain of suggestions that would all have to be approved or rejected)

Comment: It is indeed a tag wiki, and I don't have yet the 20k. Could you please have the text asking me to ''or improve'' changed, which was irritating me?

Comment: That seems like a good idea - I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

Ah! I think I figured it out.

The review queues have recently been changed to include some known bad posts as honeypots for detecting users who were mechanically reviewing in an effort to get the badges.

It seems that [these are currently detectable due to differences in the UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157808/reviewing-low-quality-posts-that-are-baits-do-not-let-you-improve-edit-them). Presumable the team is working on this.

---

Hmmm ... what I see is

[image]

with the improve button right in the middle of the cluster on the right.

Are you getting something different? On just one suggested edit or consistently?

Comment: I only see the three buttons mentioned. Not for the first time. But I cannot check consistency without losing this edit out of sight.

Comment: Wait, I thought the honeypots were only for SO for now?

Comment: @Manishearth Uhm. Well, that would make sense but I haven't been paying enough attention.